# Rails: How to initialize instance variable in new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models post and comments.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comments 
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :post
end
```

my form for creating new comment is as below

```
<%= form_for @comment , :url => post_comments_path(params[:post_id])  do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :title %>
    <%= f.submit "Add Comment" %>
<% end %>
```

I am having confusion with new action of the above form. in new action i can initialize @comment instance variable with below two ways.

```
@comment = Comment.new

or 

@post = Post.find(params[:id)
@comment = @post.comments.build(set_params)
```

my question is what is the difference between Comment.new and @post.comments.build(set_params).

Comment: The first comment will not have `post_id` property set. That's all the difference

Comment: Depending on how you handle the creation of comments, one or the other form might be preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter is preferred, because it will set `post_id` on the comment.